# Plotting a line plot in ggplot using corresponding vector inputs as x and y variables

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I post a reproducible example below:

```
a<-runif(10,5,20)
b<-runif(10,2,11)
c<-runif(10,12,27)
d<-runif(10,19,38)
e<-runif(10,4,15)
q<-runif(10,11,26)


df<-data.frame(A=a,B=b,C=c,D=d,E=e,Q=q)


vec1<-c("Q","A","B","C","D","D","E")
vec2<-c("A","B","C","D","E","Q","B")
```

I would like to produce multiple ggplot line charts using a loop through the data frame df, with the x and y variables being from vec1 and vec2.

For example, the first chart should be Q vs A, second A vs B.........last being E vs B.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Map` to create a ggplot object from each pair of columns:

```r
library(ggplot2)

plot_list <- Map(function(A, B) {
  ggplot(data.frame(x = df[[A]], y = df[[B]]), aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() +
    labs(x = A, y = B)
 }, A = vec1, B = vec2)
```

This results in a `list` of `ggplot` objects. For example, you can get the first one like this:

```r
plot_list[[1]]
```

[image]

And the second like this:

```r
plot_list[[2]]
```

[image]

Or you can plot them all on the same page like this:

```r
ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = plot_list)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This works on the example cited above, but I can't get it to work on the data frame that I have. I get an error Error in data.frame(x = joined_data[[A]], y = joined_data[[B]]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1127, 0.

Comment: The error suggests that you have got one of the column names wrong in your second vector (equivalent to `vec2` in the above example). Ensure spelling, including the case, matches exactly. You might find `names(joined_data)` helpful to make sure that they match